# Function series

Tags: analysis, functions

I'm seeking assistance in correcting my inevitable mistakes and answers to my questions.

$\textbf{Problem}$

a) Let $f_{k}(x) = 1, k\leq x \leq k+1$ and $0$ for all other values of $x$. Show that $(f_{k})$ converges uniformly to $0$ on all intervals $0<t\leq x \leq T < \infty$

b) Is it true that $\lim_{k \to \infty }\int_{0}^{\infty} f_{k}(x)dx = 0?$

c) Let $(f_{k})$ be a progression of functions on the interval $(0,\infty)$ that converges uniformly towards $f$ on every interval $0<t\leq x \leq T < \infty$. Suppose furthermore that there exists a function $g$ on $(0,\infty)$ such that $|f_{k}(x)|\leq g(x)$ for all $k$ and $x$ and that $\int_{0}^{\infty}g(x)dx < \infty$. Show that $\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{0}^{\infty}f_{k}(x)dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx$

$\textbf{Answers}$

a) I do not know how to prove this but when $k$ gets bigger and bigger the interval at which $f_k(x) = 1$ decreases which implies that $f_{k}(x) \to f(x) = 0, \text{when} \: k \to \infty$. And thus $||f_{k}(x)-0|| = max(0,\text{sup}_{x\in I} |f_{k}(x)|) = 0$ and thus $f_{k}$ converges uniformly on $I$. (Here $I$ is the interval stated above).

$\textit{Is this reasoning correct? If so, how can I make it more rigorous?}$

b) Yes, since $f_{k}(x)$ converges uniformly on $I$. $\lim_{k \to \infty }\int_{0}^{\infty} f_{k}(x)dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \text{lim}_{k \to \infty } f_{k}(x)dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}0dx = 0$

$\textit{Would this be true with the bounds replaced with any given interval}$ $J \subset I$?

c) The fact that $(f_{k})$ is uniformly convergent implies that $\lim_{k \to \infty }\int_{0}^{\infty} f_{k}(x)dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \text{lim}_{k \to \infty } f_{k}(x)dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)dx$ and since $|f_{k}(x)|\leq g(x)$ then $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)dx \leq \int_{0}^{\infty} |f(x)|dx \leq \int_{0}^{\infty} g(x)dx \leq \infty$

Have I done any mistakes, am I just incorrect in my reasoning or does everything look fine?

Thankful for any assistance!

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(a)**

Let $[t,T]$. Then evebtually, $k>T$, thus $f_k\equiv 0$ for such $k$. Thus it converges uniformly.

**(b)**

Second one is not correct, since $\int_{0}^{\infty}f_{k}(x)dx= \int_{k}^{k+1}f_{k}(x)dx=\int_{k}^{k+1}1dx=1$. Thus $\int_{0}^{\infty}f_{k}(x)dx=1\to1\neq 0 =\int_{0}^{\infty}0dx$.

**(c)**

see dominated convergence theorem

Comment: Does this mean that a function series $(f_{k})$converges uniformly does not necessarily imply that $\lim_{k \to \infty }\int_{0}^{\infty} f_{k}(x)dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \text{lim}_{k \to \infty } f_{k}(x)dx$?.

Comment: It does not converge uniformly. It converges uniformly on every bounded (in particular compact) set which does not imply that the cnvergence is uniform